# ADFS as SAML SP use case

Tags: service-provider, adfs3.0

Based on my research that ADFS (e.g. 3.0) can act as a SAML SP. What are the use cases for this? What would ADFS do once it accepted the SAML claims from an IDP? e.g. Can it do single sign-on to a backend application?

Answer (score 0):

The use case is that ADFS can be an intermediate IDP - (R-STS).

So the chain could be:

App SP --> ADFS --> SAML --> Another IDP

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I got the following to work.

F5 (IDP) -> ADFS (Receive SAML from F5 when first acting as SP, and then transforms the assertion to its own assertion when acting as an IDP) -> App (SP)

The below also works which is using F5 for IDP chaining.

ADFS (IDP) -> F5 (SP) - F5 (IDP) -> O365 (SP)